# How can I invoke vi instead of vim

Tags: vim, osx, vi

I want to use vi for better pasting.

When I use `vi` I get vim
When I type `/usr/bin/vi` I still get vim

This is on my Max OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: when you exec vim via vi softlink vim behave as original vi. Is this you search for?

Comment: "Better pasting" from Vi? How does that work?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. What pasting are you trying to accomplish? Are you aware that the `*` register corresponds to the system clipboard, so you can type `"*y` to yank your selection to the system clipboard and `"*p` to paste from the system clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I suspect you're looking for enabling `Paste` mode in Vim. You may do this as follows:

```
:set paste
```

It can be disabled with

```
:set nopaste
```

This mode is useful when you copy-paste some code snippet from your OS buffer to Vim. This will prevent Vim from adding lots of extra spaces to line beginnings making pasted text look  ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems at this point use a symlink of **vi** to the **vim** program. Calling the program in this manner enables some functionality and disables other modes of operation. More to the point, you note that you're wanting to utilize the paste functions in vi. I'm going to make the assumption that you're using **vi** on Mac OSX in the **terminal** program. To utilize the copy and paste functions you should highlight the text with your mouse and use the following keyboard combinations:

```
Command+X  - To 'cut' text from it's current position (which you can then paste somewhere else).
Command+C  - To 'Copy' any text highlighted with your mouse.
Command+V  - To 'Paste' the copied or cut text at the current cursor position.
```

Other options also exist, however, I think these three should give you a good start in what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to learn more, look at the **vi** or **vim** documentation using the command '**man vi**'.